# PHP preg_split search misses first word

Tags: php, regex, database, explode, preg-split

I'm using preg_split to find some results and it works great except (oddly) on the first word.

For example, if there is an item called "phone blue" and I search for "phone random" I get nothing, however if I search for "random phone" (or "something ph", "something phone random", etc) it finds "phone blue".

I've hunted around for different expressions and tried them (e.g. @[\W]+@ , /[\s,]+/, etc). But nothing helps. I can only presume the first attempt at finding the item (with the full string) is messing things up, but no idea how. Quite new to this!
Thanks for any help

EDIT: Forgot to note that just searching for "phone" also doesn't work.

```
function find_by_location_or_name($where) {

    // first try complete
    $this->db->where('items_location', $where);
    $this->db->or_like('items_name', $where);
    $query = $this->db->from('items_table')->get();

    // if nothing, break it up, try again
    if( !$query->num_rows) {
        $where_like = preg_split('/ /',  $where);

        $tryagain = false;

        foreach($where_like as $like) {
            if(! $tryagain) {
                $this->db->like('items_location', $like);
            } else {
                $this->db->or_like('items_name', $like);
            }
            $tryagain = true;
        }

        // Do the query
        $query = $this->db->from('items_table')->get();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for everyone's help! In the end this worked:

```
// first try complete
$this->db->where('items_location', $where);
$this->db->or_where('items_name', $where);
$query = $this->db->from('items_table')->get();

// if nothing, break it up, try again
if( !$query->num_rows) {
    $where_like = preg_split('/ /',  $where);

    $tryagain = false;

    foreach($where_like as $like) {
        if(! $tryagain) {
            $this->db->like('items_location', $like);
            $this->db->or_like('items_name', $like);
        } else {
            $this->db->like('items_name', $like);
        }
        $tryagain = true;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use preg_split instead of the normal explode function?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean to do by the `$tryagain` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code. Instead of preg_split you should do full text index and give the whole string to MySQL. Let MySQL find it for you. That is exactly what you need.

Please look at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

This link is more clear with examples:
http://www.bakale.com/mysql/myfultext.htm